# How can I remove all classes that are not named "message" from an element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div id="abc">
</div>
```

Inside that div there can be one only of the following:

```
<p class="message">
<p class="message error"></p>
<p class="message warning"></p>
<p class="message success"></p>
<p class="message loading"></p>
```

Is there a way that I can find and remove only the class from the `<p>` element that's NOT "message". I realize I could remove everything and then add what I need with .removeClass() but this won't work for me as after I previously added the message class I did some CSS changes and these will be lost if I remove all and then add again the message class.

Comment: Can you frame your question properly please ?? All the para's have message class to it.. What do you want to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the class to `"message"`. It doesn't get simpler or more semantically meaningful than simply *doing it*. There is no need to add or remove or filter or otherwise manipulate classes here.

```
$('#abc .message').attr("class", "message");
```

This also seems to meet your criteria as it doesn't "remove all", it simply *sets* the class to `"message"`. At no point is the class `message` removed from the elements.

Comment: I set the class to message when the elements were created and then applied an inline style to make some changes. Not sure but if I set the class to message will that mean the original message CSS is applied causing my inline styles to be nullified?

Comment: No. Explicitly set ("inline") styles are stored completely separately from styles applied to class names, and explicit styles take precedence. You can safely do this without losing your inline styles.

Comment: @Marilou - inline styles override styles inherited from style sheets via class names or other style rules.  So, removing some class names will not cause inline styles to be any less effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
$('.message').removeClass().addClass('message');
```

You note that you have thought of this method, but think that previous CSS manipulations will be removed, but you are wrong - CSS manipulations done with javascript get applied directly to the element (via the `style` attribute/property), so they will not be removed.

Also, since there are only four other classes that could be attached (in your example), you could always just do:

```
$('.message').removeClass('error warning success loading');
```

Comment: Thanks. I note your comments about inline not being removed. I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the class names you want to remove you can try this

```
$('p').removeClass('error warning success loading')
```

Comment: Classes are stored in a single `class` attribute as a series of space-separated names. This involves a ton of needless string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The `.removeClass()` method can take a callback function that receives the current class list as a parameter and that should return the class(es) to remove, so you can do some variation on the following:

```
var classToKeep = "message";    
$("#abc p").removeClass(function(i,c) {
    return c.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + classToKeep + "\\b"), "");
});
```

I think meagar and ahren's answers provide better solutions, but since you asked specifically about how to remove all classes except one...

Comment: **Tremendously** overwrought but technically valid :p

Comment: @meagar - "Tremendously"? I was shooting for "ludicrously"... but it does do _exactly_ what the OP asked for...